# Why does Java's Area#equals method not override Object#equals?

Tags: java, equals

I just ran into a problem caused by Java's `java.awt.geom.Area#equals(Area)` method. The problem can be simplified to the following unit test:

```
@org.junit.Test
public void testEquals() {
    java.awt.geom.Area a = new java.awt.geom.Area();
    java.awt.geom.Area b = new java.awt.geom.Area();
    assertTrue(a.equals(b)); // -> true

    java.lang.Object o = b;
    assertTrue(a.equals(o)); // -> false
}
```

After some head scratching and debugging, I finally saw in the JDK source, that the signature of the `equals` method in `Area` looks like this:

```
public boolean equals(Area other)
```

Note that it does *not* `@Override` the normal `equals` method from `Object`, but instead just overloads the method with a more concrete type. Thus, the two calls in the example above end up calling different implementations of `equals`.

As this behavior has been present since Java 1.2, I assume it is not considered a bug. I am, therefore, more interested in finding out *why* the decision was made to *not* properly override the `equals` method, but at the same time provide an overloaded variant. (Another hint that this was an actual decision made is the absence of an overwritten `hashCode()` method.)

My only guess would be that the authors feared that the slow `equals` implementation for areas is unsuitable for comparing equality when placing `Area`s in `Set`,`Map`,etc. datastructures. (In the above example, you could add `a` to a `HashSet`, and although `b` is equal to `a`, calling `contains(b)` will fail.) Then again, why did they not just name the questionable method in a way that does not clash with such a fundamental concept as the `equals` method ?

Comment: Note that `hashCode` is also not overridden. I think what they are doing here is just providing a "comparison" method that just happens to have the same name as `Object.equals()`. Personally, I would have given it a different name to avoid confusion.

Comment: The Java API does not always follow the best practices, and this looks like an oversight.  Try raising this question on the Oracle developer email lists and see what the official word is.  If it is an oversight, Sun/Oracle have always been very reluctant to make API changes post release.  Which could mean that it started as an oversight that made it into a release, and is now just frozen in time.

Comment: See [Bug 4391558](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-4391558)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

RealSkeptic linked to [JDK-4391558](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-4391558) in a comment above. The [comment](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-4391558?focusedCommentId=12555043&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-12555043) in that bug explains the reasoning:

> The problem with overriding equals(Object) is that you must also
>   override hashCode() to return a value which guarantees that equals()
>   is true only if the hashcodes of the two objects are also equal.

but:

> The problem here is that Area.equals(Area) does not perform a very
>   straight-forward comparison. It painstakingly examines each and every
>   piece of geometry in the two Areas and tests to see if they cover the
>   same enclosed spaces. Two Area objects could have a completely
>   different description of the same enclosed space and equals(Area)
>   would detect that they were the same.

So basically we're left with an array of not-so-pleasant options, such as:

> deprecate equals(Area) and create an alternate name for that
>   operation, such as "areasEqual" so as to avoid the confusion.
>   Unfortunately, the old method would remain and would be linkable and
>   would trap many people who were intending to invoke the equals(Object)
>   version.

or:

> deprecate equals(Area) and change its implementation to be exactly
>   that of equals(Object) so as to avoid semantic problems if the wrong
>   method is called. Create a new method with a different name to avoid
>   confusion to implement the old functionality provided by equals(Area).

or:

> implement equals(Object) to call equals(Area) and implement a dummy
>   hashCode() which honors the equals/hashCode contract in a degenerate
>   way by returning a constant. This would make the hashCode method
>   essentially useless and make Area objects nearly useless as keys in a
>   HashMap or Hashtable.

or other ways to modify the `equals(Area)` behavior that would either change its semantics or make it inconsistent with `hashCode`.

Looks like changing this method is deemed by the maintainers to be neither feasible (because neither option outlined in the bug comment quite solves the problem) nor important (since the method, as implemented, is quite slow and would probably only ever return true when comparing an instance of an `Area` with itself, as the commenter suggests).

Answer (score 0):

"Why does Java's Area#equals method not override Object#equals?"

Because overriding is not necessary for overloaded methods where the parameters are of differing types.

> An overridden method would have the exact same method name, return type, number of parameters, and types of parameters as the method in the parent class, and the only difference would be the definition of the method.

This case does not compel us to override but it is overloading as it follows these rules:

> 1.) The number of parameters is different for the methods.
>
> 2.) The parameter types are different (like  changing a parameter that was a float to an int).

"why did they not just name the questionable method in a way that does not clash with such a fundamental concept as the equals method?"

Because this could trip people up going into the future.  If we had a time machine to the 90's we could do it without this concern.

Comment: You've misunderstood his question. The question is about why you'd overload it and not override it. The bug linked by @RealSkeptic provides some insights.

Comment: @DeepakBala I specified why you would not override it, and how the concept follows the rules of overloading.  Not sure what you mean as it seems I answered the question, can you clarify?

Comment: Sorry, but as I stated in my question I am quite well aware of what overriding and overloading are and when each can be used or not. But as @DeepakBala pointed out, this is completely missing my question. I can see (and understand) the status quo fine, but wanted to know why this seemingly problematic decision was made in the first place.

Comment: @Frank I think it makes sense.  "Because overriding is not necessary for overloaded methods where the parameters are of differing types." This is the priori, what is left to question?  The idea may have been implemented 'better' in the sense of clarity, but the decision is not incorrect logically. Am I wrong?