# Java reflection to call overloaded method Area.equals(Area)

Tags: java, reflection, equals

As discussed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28563304/why-does-javas-areaequals-method-not-override-objectequals), the `equals` method of `java.awt.geom.Area` is defined as

`public boolean equals(Area other)`

instead of overriding the `equals` method from `Object`. That question covers the "why", and I'm interested in "how can I force Java to use the most appropriate `equals` method".

Consider this example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Class<?> cls = Area.class;
    Area a1 = new Area(new Rectangle2D.Double(1, 2, 3, 4));
    Area a2 = new Area(new Rectangle2D.Double(1, 2, 3, 4));
    System.out.println("Areas equal: " + a1.equals(a2)); // true

    Object o1 = (Object) a1;
    Object o2 = (Object) a2;
    System.out.println("Objects equal: " + o1.equals(o2)); // false

    // Given only cls, o1, and o2, how can I get .equals() to return true?
    System.out.println("cls.cast() approach : " + cls.cast(o1).equals(cls.cast(o2))); // false

    try {
        Method equalsMethod = cls.getMethod("equals", cls); // Exception thrown in most cases
        System.out.println("Reflection approach: " + equalsMethod.invoke(o1, o2)); // true (when cls=Area.class)
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

My question is: given `o1`, `o2`, and `cls`, where `o1` and `o2` are guaranteed to be instances of `cls` (or a subclass), how can I call the most appropriate `equals` method? Assuming `cls` is `X.class`, I would like the following behavior:

- If `X` defines `X.equals(X)`, this is the "most appropriate" choice. (Example: `X` is `Area`)
- Otherwise, if `X` defines `X.equals(Object)`, this is the second-most-appropriate choice. (Example: `X` is `Rectangle2D`)
- If neither of the above are true, I want to call `Object.equals(Object)` as a fallback. (Example: `X` is `Path2D`)

In principle, I could use reflection to check for each of the above method signatures, but that seems pretty heavy-handed. Is there a simpler way?

Edit for clarity: `o1`, `o2`, and `cls` all vary at runtime so I *cannot* statically cast like `((Area) o1).equals((Area) o2)`, since `cls` might not be `Area.class` at all times. However it is guaranteed that `cls.isAssignableFrom(o1.getClass())` and `cls.isAssignableFrom(o2.getClass())` are both `true`.

Comment: If you just want to convert false to true, you could use '!' operator as '!o1.equals(o2)'

Comment: @BadshahTracker I'm sorry but how does that help solve my problem? I'm well aware of what `!` does.

Comment: Your question doesn't seem to be crystal clear, it's a little confusing. Edit it to provide neat information in simple words. Just describe your problem.

Comment: @BadshahTracker I honestly don't know how I can make my question more clear. As already stated, I have two objects and their class. I want to somehow call the most appropriate `equals` method as described by the bullet-point examples.

Comment: @pkpnd, I don't quite understand why given your requirements for method resolution the first thing you go for is reflection. There is no need. Look up how dynamic method call resolution happens. You only need to cast the two to appropriate types.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov Thanks for the suggestion but I've already tried `cls.cast(o2)` (in the code example) which doesn't solve the problem. Note that `cls` varies at runtime so I _cannot_ statically cast like `((Area) o1).equals((Area) o2)`.

Comment: @pkpnd, What, your code could randomly try comparing two `Area` instances with giving it a `Rectangle2D.class`? My guess: no. Just write static casts, you only need 3 logical branches here.

Comment: @pkpnd The cls.cast cannot resolve your problem, because it does not return an Area. You've defined Area.class as Class<?> and not Class<Area>. So, the compiler does not know which type of object is returned by your cast call. If possible, stick to M. Prokhorov suggestion, it's the best I see.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov Sorry, maybe I wasn't clear -- all of `o1`, `o2` and `cls` vary at runtime. Yes, `o1` and `o2` could both be `Rectangle2D` instances, in which case `cls` is `Rectangle2D.class`. `o1` and `o2` could also be of _any other type_, so no I cannot have static casts.

Comment: @pkpnd, that means your question text is wrong. You don't seem to try and select a "best match". On the other hand the "also be *any* other type" case falls under last bullet of your requirement. You again didn't convince me you can't actually just have static casts in there.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov There could be other classes that behave like `Area`, meaning they define `OtherClass.equals(OtherClass)` instead of `OtherClass.equals(Object)`. In that case, I want to use `OtherClass.equals(OtherClass)` instead of the last bullet point's `Object.equals(Object)`. And clearly I can't statically list out all classes of this kind. And yes, this is meant to be used in a completely type-general way -- there is no small set of types that I'm expecting to encounter.

Comment: @pkpnd, you actually totally can list list all the classes that are like that. You have to remember: `Area`'s `Area.equals(Area)` is not a general-purpose `equals()` method. You talk like you defining some kind of semantics-driven library method, it's entirely OK to both state in method contract what it'll be doind, and implement it for selected classes that specifically said to follow this contract.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov I hate to be rude but please don't lecture me about the needs of my application. I said, I _cannot_ branch based on a hardcoded list of classes. I am in fact writing a library method that takes _any_ two objects `o1` and `o2`, and returns whether or not they are equal. So far my method checks for `null`s, sets `cls = o1.getClass()`, checks `cls.isAssignableFrom(o2.getClass())`, and finally returns `o1.equals(o2)`. My problem is, I've found that this fails for instances of `Area` and I'd like a solution. I refuse to have `Area` in the source code of my general-purpose method.

Comment: @pkpnd, if you as an implementor of a general-purpose method is OK that your method will return `true` given two objects `A` and `B` where having `map = singletonMap(A, VAL);` the simple call `map.contains(B)` would return `false`, then just use your existing reflection-based approach. I feel like I've said enough here to convince you that a general-purpose method would be aligned with a common definition of `equals()` as consistent with `hashCode`. Which `Area.equals(Area)` is not, thus not being anywhere near "general-purpose".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second and third bullets (use `X.equals(Object)` or fallback to `Object.equals(Object)`) do not require any effort, as that’s what will happen anyway when calling the overridable method `Object.equals(Object)`, it will use the most specific overriding method it can find.

So the only remaining task, is to invoke the `X.equals(X)` method, if applicable. To minimize the associated costs, you may cache the result. Since Java 7, there is the class [`ClassValue`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/?java/lang/ClassValue.html) allowing to associate information with a class, in a thread safe, lazily evaluated and efficiently looked up way, still supporting garbage collection of the key class if needed.

So, a Java 7 solution may look like:

```
import java.lang.invoke.*;

public final class EqualsOperation extends ClassValue<MethodHandle> {
    public static boolean equals(Object o, Object p) {
        if(o == p) return true;
        if(o == null || p == null) return false;
        Class<?> t1 = o.getClass(), t2 = p.getClass();
        if(t1 != t2) t1 = commonClass(t1, t2);
        try {
            return (boolean)OPS.get(t1).invokeExact(o, p);
        } catch(RuntimeException | Error unchecked) {
            throw unchecked;
        } catch(Throwable ex) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(ex);
        }
    }
    private static Class<?> commonClass(Class<?> t1, Class<?> t2) {
        while(t1 != Object.class && !t1.isAssignableFrom(t2)) t1 = t1.getSuperclass();
        return t1;
    }
    static final EqualsOperation OPS = new EqualsOperation();
    static final MethodHandle FALLBACK;
    static {
        try {
            FALLBACK = MethodHandles.lookup().findVirtual(Object.class, "equals",
                MethodType.methodType(boolean.class, Object.class));
        } catch (ReflectiveOperationException ex) {
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected MethodHandle computeValue(Class<?> type) {
        try {
            return MethodHandles.lookup()
                .findVirtual(type, "equals", MethodType.methodType(boolean.class, type))
                .asType(FALLBACK.type());
        } catch(ReflectiveOperationException ex) {
            return FALLBACK;
        }
    }
}
```

You may test it with

```
Object[] examples1 = { 100, "foo",
    new Area(new Rectangle(10, 20)), new Area(new Rectangle(20, 20)) };
Object[] examples2 = { new Integer(100), new String("foo"),// enforce a!=b
   new Area(new Rectangle(10, 20)) };
for(Object a: examples1) {
    for(Object b: examples2) {
        System.out.printf("%30s %30s: %b%n", a, b, EqualsOperation.equals(a, b));
    }
}
```

Starting with Java 8, we can generate instances of functional interfaces at runtime, which likely improves performance, as then, we are not performing any reflective operation anymore, after encountering a type for the first time:

```
import java.lang.invoke.*;
import java.util.function.BiPredicate;

public final class EqualsOperation extends ClassValue<BiPredicate<Object,Object>> {
    public static boolean equals(Object o, Object p) {
        if(o == p) return true;
        if(o == null || p == null) return false;
        Class<?> t1 = o.getClass(), t2 = p.getClass();
        if(t1 != t2) t1 = commonClass(t1, t2);
        return OPS.get(t1).test(o, p); // test(...) is not reflective
    }
    private static Class<?> commonClass(Class<?> t1, Class<?> t2) {
        while(t1 != Object.class && !t1.isAssignableFrom(t2)) t1 = t1.getSuperclass();
        return t1;
    }
    static final EqualsOperation OPS = new EqualsOperation();
    static final BiPredicate<Object,Object> FALLBACK = Object::equals;

    @Override
    protected BiPredicate<Object,Object> computeValue(Class<?> type) {
        if(type == Object.class) return FALLBACK;
        try {
            MethodType decl = MethodType.methodType(boolean.class, type);
            MethodHandles.Lookup lookup = MethodHandles.lookup();
            MethodHandle mh = lookup.findVirtual(type, "equals", decl);
            decl = mh.type();
            BiPredicate<Object,Object> p = (BiPredicate<Object,Object>)
                LambdaMetafactory.metafactory(lookup, "test",
                    MethodType.methodType(BiPredicate.class), decl.erase(), mh, decl)
                .getTarget().invoke();
            return p;
        } catch(Throwable ex) {
            return FALLBACK;
        }
    }
}
```

The usage is just like with the other variant.

A critical point here, is the accessibility. I assume, you only want to support `public` methods declared by `public` classes anyway. Still, fine tuning might be needed for Java 9+, if crossing the module border. To support custom `X.equals(X)` methods declared in application code, it may need to open itself to your library for reflective access.

The problems of an equality function not matching the equality logic of other code (like collections), have been discussed in the comment at your question already. Here, similar issues as with, e.g. `IdentityHashMap`, may arise; handle with care…